# circulos dentro de un circulo mayor como reducir este código al minimo?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, revisión-de-código

Hola pueden asesorarme del como puedo reducir este código al mínimo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Dibujando</title>
        <style>
            #canvas {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" height="600" width="600"></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
            var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
            var radius = 250;
            var e = 3;
            var x = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(radius / e, 2) - Math.pow((radius / e) / 2, 2)) * 2;

            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
            context.stroke();
            context.closePath();

            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius / e, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
            context.stroke();

            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(centerX - ((radius / e) * 2), centerY, radius / e, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
            context.stroke();
            context.closePath();

            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(centerX + ((radius / e) * 2), centerY, radius / e, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
            context.stroke();
            context.closePath();

            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(centerX - (radius / e), centerY - x , radius / e, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
            context.stroke();
            context.closePath();

            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(centerX + (radius / e), centerY - x , radius / e, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
            context.stroke();
            context.closePath();

            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(centerX - (radius / e), centerY + x , radius / e, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
            context.stroke();
            context.closePath();

            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(centerX + (radius / e), centerY + x , radius / e, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
            context.stroke();
            context.closePath();

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podías empezar por meter la lógica de dibujar un círculo en una función.

Algo así:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 250;
var e = 3;
var x = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(radius / e, 2) - Math.pow((radius / e) / 2, 2)) * 2;
var pi2 = Math.PI * 2;

function circulo(x, y, radius){
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, pi2, false);
  context.stroke();
  context.closePath();
}

circulo(centerX, centerY, radius);
radius = radius/e;
circulo(centerX, centerY, radius);
circulo(centerX - radius*2, centerY, radius);
circulo(centerX + radius*2, centerY, radius);
circulo(centerX - radius, centerY - x, radius);
circulo(centerX + radius, centerY - x, radius);
circulo(centerX - radius, centerY + x, radius);
circulo(centerX + radius, centerY + x, radius);
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="600" width="600"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Con la herramienta [refresh-sf.com](http://refresh-sf.com/) puedes minficar y obfuscar online tu código.

[Ver código minificado](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/16bfb0b2cf8fbeb7a671568779ab8465/raw/9d1fe5644d9faf5dccb714a0239a550f68c40b6c/app.min.js)

```js
var t=document.getElementById("canvas"),a=t.getContext("2d"),e=t.width/2,h=t.height/2,P=250,o=3,r=2*Math.sqrt(Math.pow(P/o,2)-Math.pow(P/o/2,2));a.beginPath(),a.arc(e,h,P,0,2*Math.PI,!1),a.stroke(),a.closePath(),a.beginPath(),a.arc(e,h,P/o,0,2*Math.PI,!1),a.stroke(),a.beginPath(),a.arc(e-P/o*2,h,P/o,0,2*Math.PI,!1),a.stroke(),a.closePath(),a.beginPath(),a.arc(e+P/o*2,h,P/o,0,2*Math.PI,!1),a.stroke(),a.closePath(),a.beginPath(),a.arc(e-P/o,h-r,P/o,0,2*Math.PI,!1),a.stroke(),a.closePath(),a.beginPath(),a.arc(e+P/o,h-r,P/o,0,2*Math.PI,!1),a.stroke(),a.closePath(),a.beginPath(),a.arc(e-P/o,h+r,P/o,0,2*Math.PI,!1),a.stroke(),a.closePath(),a.beginPath(),a.arc(e+P/o,h+r,P/o,0,2*Math.PI,!1),a.stroke(),a.closePath();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="600" width="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: creo que existe un algoritmo para que dibujar esos circulos interiores y que no sea estatico

Comment: No busco minificar el código busco optimizar ya sea con un ciclo o reescribir el código de otra manera.